# How to append rolling index BEFORE file extension in log filename

Tags: log4net

I am using the `RollingLogFileAppender` and it works great and it's rolling over into new files.  But it's adding the .1, .2, etc at the very end of the file.  So I end up with `.log.1`, `.log.2`, etc.  So every file technically has a new extension that explorer doesn't know,  so I can't just double click on a file to open.

How can I get the rolling file appender to insert that index BEFORE the file extension?

What I want is

- .1.log
- .2.log

Bonus would be for the current file to always be `.0.log`, that way they always sort correctly in explorer.

EDIT: added my current config settings

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
      <file value="App_Data\\Logs\\" />
      <datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.log'" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Composite" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>


    <logger name="File">
      <level value="All" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: Please show entire log4net config

Comment: I've updated the question to include my current settings

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need to use the PreserveLogFileNameExtension property on the RollingFileAppender.

See the **following** questions:

[Log4net appender filename issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833464/log4net-appender-filename-issue)

[Log4net RollingFileAppender Size rollingStyle file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608591/log4net-rollingfileappender-size-rollingstyle-file-extension)